# How to Run python program with libraries installed in virtual environment using IDE like PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, virtualenv

How do I tell IDE like PyCharm that my libraries are installed on virtual environment ?

Example : I have openCV libraries installed in a virtual environment.If I try to run the program on PyCharm IDE it will show import like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pycharm+virtualenv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select your virtual environment in Pycharm settings: `File->New Project Settings -> Preferences for New Projects -> Project Interpreter`.

From there you can select a found environment or click "+" in Project Interpreter list to add your own env from a path. This env will be added to the list. Also you are able to add new libs using "+" in the end of current libs list.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a moment to explore here.

[image]